# Require login to view content of MediaWiki site

Tags: mediawiki, wiki

Is there a way to hide the content of my wiki site? I want to allow users with an account to view the content after login. Is this possible under Mediawiki?

Comment: Your question seems [off topic](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) for Stack Overflow. It might be better suited for our sister site, http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, of *course* it's possible!  That's why MediaWiki has users and groups!

- http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:User_rights
- http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Security
- http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Preventing_access

Comment: And, in particular, http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Preventing_access#Restrict_viewing_of_all_pages

Comment: @paulsm4 Thanks. Can I allow users access only to some particular pages instead of all pages?